# How do I reconnect my Bluetooth mouse to Windows 10 after pairing it to another device, without un-pairing and re-pairing?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth

I know this is possible on Linux and Android. Just select the device in your paired device list while the mouse is in pairing mode and it will re-pair, even after previously being connected to something else. However, I see no such option in Windows. Just a "Remove device" button.

Any workarounds I can use, such as a third-party Bluetooth device manager or a hidden Windows feature? Thanks.